# Сравнить данные из SQLite с вводимыми данными

Tags: android, sqlite

Пытаюсь создать тест. Пользователь видит марку автомобиля и вводит название в поле `editText`, если ответ правильный, поле `editText` выделяется зеленым, если нет, то красным (без использования кнопки)

Проблема в том, что я не знаю, как сравнить данные из базы данных с вводимыми данными, возможно более опытные форумчане помогут с ответом?

**DatabaseHelper.java**:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME= "answers.db";
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "answers";
public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "right_answer";
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table answers (_id integer " +
        "primary key autoincrement , right_answer not null);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    onCreate(db);
 }

}
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText et_one_one, et_one_two, et_one_three, et_one_four, et_one_five;
DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
SQLiteDatabase db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    et_one_one = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_one);
    et_one_two = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_two);
    et_one_three = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_three);
    et_one_four = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_four);
    et_one_five = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_five);

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db = databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues newValues = new ContentValues();

    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "maserati");
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "mercedes");
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "bmw");
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "audi");
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "dodge");
    newValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME, "ford");

    db.insert("answers", null, newValues);

}

public void Compare(View view){

    String one = et_one_one.getText().toString();
    String two = et_one_two.getText().toString();
    String three = et_one_three.getText().toString();
    String four = et_one_four.getText().toString();
    String fifth = et_one_five.getText().toString();


}
}
```

Comment: То есть у вас на экране несколько картинок и под каждой `EditText` и в каждый нужно вписать правильное значение, соответствующее изображенному на картинке над ним?

Comment: да, именно так ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем тут БД как бы не очень нужна, так как вам все равно надо сравнивать ввод с эталоном (правильным названием), то логичнее просто полученную из `EditText` строку сравнивать с ожидаемой в этом поле.

Если планируется большое количество таких вопросов и все дело надо как то автоматизировать, чтобы не писать кучу однотипных строк, то необходимо как то связать (синхронизировать) конкретные `EditText` с записями в БД, чтобы можно было сделать заключение о соответствии правильному ответу.
Как вариант предлагаю рассмотреть привязку через тэги и синхронизацию по `ID` БД . К каждому `EditText` привязать уникальный тэг, хранящий соответствующий правильному ответу `ID` в БД (например для первого `EditText`будет правильный ответ `maserati`, который соответствует ID = 0):

```
et_one_one = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_one_one);
et_one_one.setTag(0);
```

Теперь нам надо найти в БД строку соответствующую введенной в `EditText` и сравнить ее `ID` с правильным:

```
public void Compare(View view){

    String one = et_one_one.getText().toString();
    int oneId = et_one_one.getTag();
    if (isRight(one, oneId)) { // правильный ответ};
    ....
}
```

сам метод определения правильного соответствия. Метод возвратит `true` только когда введенная в `EditText`строка имеется в БД и ее `ID` соответствует эталонному:

```
public  boolean isRight(String searchName, int trueId) { 
    final int NUMBER_ID_COLUMN = 0;
    boolean result = false;
    searchName = searchName.toLowerCase(); // переводим все буквы в нижний регистр       
    String select = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " =?";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(select, new String[] {searchName});
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0){ cursor.moveToFirst();
                                result = (cursor.getInt(NUMBER_ID_COLUMN) == trueId)? true:false;}
    cursor.close();
    return result;
}
```

В общем то можно обойтись и без тегов вовсе, а просто вторым аргументом в `isRight()` передавать, с какой строкой сравнивать.

Все это все так же муторно, можно ввести некоторую автоматизацию при динамическом формировании `EditText` в случае с тегами и `ID`, но я бы порекомендовал ознакомиться, как сделана викторина [в этом примере](https://github.com/feriatos/GeoQuiz). Да, там немного другая логика ответов, но это не слишком принципиально для общего алгоритма действий. Если вам понадобится подробнейшее описание к этому коду, то оно есть в книге: Брайн Харди , Билл Филипс - "Программирование под Android", 2014 г. - пример из этой книги - первое приложение "GeoQuiz".

Еще похожий пример есть в книге: Дейтел - "Android для программистов. Создаем приложения", 2012 г. - Глава 6: Приложение Flag Quiz Game. [Сэмпл на GitHub](https://github.com/michaelbiby/FlagQuizEnhanced_Android)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, как я понял, при таком подходе, если пользователь введет под картинкой bmw марку mercedes, то будет прав, так как в базе есть марка mercedes. Ни правильнее ли будет привязать listener к каждому editText, как советует Виталий? Но при этом, если у меня будет их 100, к каждому привязывать?

Comment: а.. да .. этот метод только проверяет - есть ли такая строка в БД, а не ее соответствие с эталонной. Сейчас исправим.

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать слушателя привязанного к EditText:

```
et_one_one.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
       //После изменения edt
    }
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){
      //До изменения edt
    }
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
      //Во время изменения edt
    }
});
```

Я полагаю, что вам надо в методе afterTextChanged Взять значение из базы и значение из EditText и сравнить, а потом исходя из результата сравнения применить тот или иной цвет.