# Архитектурная оптимизация кода

Tags: android, оптимизация

Делаю приложение тест. На дисплее отображаются фразы которые нужно продолжить написав в поле editText названия авто.

Как правильно оптимизировать код(возможно вынести варианты в отдельный массив или класс), если в перспективе у меня будет больше таких фраз разложенных по разным уровням?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 private boolean isValid(final EditText source, final String expected) {
    String actual = source.getText().toString();
    return expected.equals(actual);
}

private void visualizeValidity(final EditText source, final boolean isValid) {
    int backgroundColor = (isValid) ? Color.GREEN : Color.RED;
    source.setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
}

private boolean checkEditText(final EditText source, final String expected) {
    boolean valid = isValid(source, expected);
    visualizeValidity(source, valid);

    return valid;

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText carOneText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car1);
    final EditText carTwoText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car2);
    final EditText carThreeText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.car3);

    Button buttonCheck = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCheck);

    buttonCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            boolean allTextsValid = (
                    checkEditText(carOneText, getString(R.string.maserati) &
                            checkEditText(carTwoText, getString(R.string.mercedes) &
                            checkEditText(carThreeText, getString(R.string.bmw)
            );

            if (allTextsValid) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Предлагаю вам взять новый код и вставить в этот вопрос. Тогда можно будет дать хорошие ответы, а не только общие ссылки. Из всех ваших вопросов этот потенциально самый ценный, т.к. тема важная и используется часто.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, воспользовался вашим советом, а как поднять этот вопрос?

Comment: Ну вот вы его обновили, он некоторое время провисит в топе новых вопросов. Пока висит, можете почитать вот это: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: @НиколайБойко, для начала хотелось бы понять, у вас приложение, в котором все экраны имеют одинаковый layout, а главное отличие это текстовки и ответы?

Comment: @ВиталийОбидейко, нет layout разные. Да, идет TextView и рядом editText

Comment: @НиколайБойко, я просто к чему веду, если у вас набор view и их количество совпадает для каждого экрана с вопросами, то нет смысла переходить на новое активити, есть смысл перенаполнить текущее, вплоть до того, что изменить фон, если это требуется. Вам так будет проще вести учет ответов и статистику, а в идеале, по ресурсам будет выгодно.

Comment: Видите ли .. весь этот ресурс работает не так, как вы им пытаетесь пользоваться - это не форум для мозговых штурмов, а решение конкретных проблем. Пользователь формулирует ОДНУ  проблему, другие, по мере возможности, публикуют решения. Общий смысл в том, что решение КОНКРЕТНОЙ проблемы поможет другим не искать ответа, а получить уже готовый - здесь не персональные консультации для новичков. Не надо переписывать вопросы в стиле: "а что, если я теперь так сделаю", "теперь я все переделал и хочу добавить это" и тп. Так же подумайте, полезно ли будет то, что вы спрашиваете кому то еще, кроме вас.

Comment: @pavlofff, спасибо за комментарий, я попытался поправить вопрос стараясь сделать его актуальным, но видимо это у меня не сильно получилось.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужен [string-array](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133503/). Вообще стоит взять себе за правило не пихать стринги в классы. После того как массив будет описан его можно будет использовать как обычный массив и для проверки достаточно будет использовать contains.

Так же если полей будет много, то гораздо рациональнее запихать их в кастомный listView.

Comment: А зачем мне listView, если он в моем случае кроме как прокрутка содержащая максимум до 10 строк, ни каких функций осуществлять не будет, я использую ScrollView. А как будет функционировать string array, из статьи я понял, что к каждому edit-text я не смогу привязать свой стринг, чтобы в поле мерседес нельзя было ввести бмв, даже если она есть в массиве.

"Вообще стоит взять себе за правило не пихать стринги в классы." Вы про сравнение (t1.equals("maserati"))? Не могли бы вы показать, как это убрать в отдельный метод?

Comment: Смотрите это очень просто. Если использовать listView то можно будет получить задарма idшник editText, в который был осуществлен ввод, думаю это просто. Так же мы можем получить из ресурсов описанный ранее массив в string-array и имея idшник полученный ранее проверить совпадают ли названия. Весь метод проверки займет 2 - 3 строчки и ему будет все равно на изменения в ресурсах. Так же можно пойти дальше и описать в одном массиве элемент типа фраза которая выводится| название марки. В этом случае для добавления элементов вообще не придется в код лезть, только в ресурсы.

Comment: И вы сделали тот же listView только в профиль.

Comment: Да очень просто надо только разобраться как кастомный listView делать. В гугле тонны инфы на этот счет.

Answer (score 0):

Если браться серьезно за это дело, то вам нужно все хранить в предзаполненной базе даных. Только для этого прийдется поразбираться как работать с SQLite, как использовать файлик базы даных созданый ранее и тд.

Comment: [с этого](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/442870/177345) и начинали ..

Comment: OMG. Это просто невозможно собрать всю информацию про эту программу.

Comment: @pavlofff: Мда, случай непростой.